# profile page on php codeigneter still move to the login page if i change the url to the login even though already logged

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, login-script

i have a problem, i have login page, it will direct to the profile if we input the correct email & password, but the problem is when i change the url to the login, it still move to the login page, how can i block the login page if I'm already logged in so that will be dirrect to the profile although the url i change to the login page it's still direct to the profile page.

> below is the code :

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['email'] = $session_data['email'];
        $this->load->view('view_profile', $data);
    }else{
        redirect('login','refresh');
    }
}
public function logout(){
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(site_url('home'),'refresh');
}
```

}

> this is the userdata('logged_in')

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|callback_basisdata_cek');
            if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
                $this->load->view('view_home');
            }else{
                redirect(base_url('index.php/profile'),'refresh');
        }
    }

    function basisdata_cek($password){
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $result = $this->login->login($email,$password);
        if($result){
            $sess_array = array();
            foreach($result as $row){
                $sess_array = $arrayName = array('email'=>$row->email, 'password'=>$row->password);
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_array);
            }
            return true;
        }else{

            $this->session->set_flashdata('basisdata_cek', 'Invalid email or password');
            redirect(base_url('index.php/login'),'refresh');
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the value of $this->session->userdata('logged_in') ?

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes there i was edit the code, and i put the value of $this->session->userdata('logged_in')

Comment: possible maybe you are destroying session on the first hand in Login class....

Comment: You are passing a value to your session variable logged_in so the value of this variable is not boolean you can try this  if($this->session->has_userdata('logged_in') OR $this->session->has_userdata('logged_in') != '' OR !empty($this->session->has_userdata('logged_in')))

Answer (score 0):

**BEST Practice**

Always create User / Login Controller separate, you will have more space to create functionalities like user role check and redirecting the user to their role specific dashboards / profiles.

Keep Login / Logout check functions in a parent controller and extend your controller from that controller. For example, create a controller named My_Controller and put your isLoggedin check and logout functions in it.

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        if(!empty($this->session->userdata['id'])&& $this->session->userdata['type']=='admin')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

Then create your user or login controller to render the login page and implementing login functionality

```
class Login extends My_Controller
{
 public function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   $this->load->library("security");
 }

 public function index()
 {
   if(!$this->isLoggedin()) // if the user is not logged in render login screen
   {
    if($_POST) // or if($this->input->post)
    {
     $data=$this->security->xss_clean($_POST);
     $user=$this->user_model->checkUser($data);
     if(!empty($user))
     {
       $this->session->set_userdata($user);
       redirect(base_url().'profile');
     }
     else
     {
       $data['errors']='Wrong Credentials';
       $this->load->view('login',$data);
     }
   }
   else
   {
     $this->load->view('login');
   }
  }
  else // but if the user is logged in , take him to profile. 
  {
   redirect(base_url().'profile');
  }
}
```

And in your profile Controller

```
class Profile extends My_Controller
{
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('user_model');
 }

 public function index()
 {
  // if user is not logged in , redirect him back to login screen. 
  if(!$this->isLoggedin()){ redirect(base_url().'login');}
  $userId=$this->session->userdata['id']; // this index depends on the field name
  $data['user']=$this->user_model->getUserDataById($userId);
  $this->load->view('profile',$data);
 }
}
```